# Split a column into 2 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

```
 I have this dataframe 

      CC.Number       Date Time Accident.Type              Location.1
    1 12T008826 07/01/2012 1630            PD  (39.26699, -76.560642)
    2 12L005385 07/02/2012 1229            PD (39.000549, -76.399312)
    3 12L005388 07/02/2012 1229            PD  (39.00058, -76.399267)
    4 12T008851 07/02/2012  445            PI   (39.26367, -76.56648)
    5 12T008858 07/02/2012  802            PD (39.240862, -76.599017)
    6 12T008860 07/02/2012  832            PD   (39.27022, -76.63926)
```

I want to split the column Location.1 to "alt" and "lng" columns to be like

```
  CC.Number       Date Time Accident.Type      alt       lng
1 12T008826 07/01/2012 1630            PD  39.26699    -76.560642
2 12L005385 07/02/2012 1229            PD  39.000549   -76.399312
3 12L005388 07/02/2012 1229            PD  39.00058    -76.399267
```

I tried

```
location <- md$Location.1
location1 <- substring(location, 2)
location2 <- substr(location1, 1, nchar(location1)-1 )
location3 <-  strsplit(location2, ",")
```

but stuck at converting location3  from list to dataframe

I tried

```
ocdf<-data.frame(location2)
colnames(locdf)[1] = c("x")
df <- separate(location, col=x,into = c("lat","log"), sep = ",")
```

but I get an error

> Error in UseMethod("separate_") :  no applicable method for
>   'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Answer (score 4):

`separate` from `tidyr` also works

```
library(tidyr)
# Sub out the parentheses
df$Location.1 <- gsub("[()]", "", df$Location.1)

separate(df, col = Location.1, into = c("lat","long"), sep = ",")
#  CC.Number       Date Time Accident.Type       lat        long
#1 12T008826 07/01/2012 1630            PD  39.26699  -76.560642
#2 12L005385 07/02/2012 1229            PD 39.000549  -76.399312
#3 12L005388 07/02/2012 1229            PD  39.00058  -76.399267
#4 12T008851 07/02/2012  445            PI  39.26367   -76.56648
#5 12T008858 07/02/2012  802            PD 39.240862  -76.599017
#6 12T008860 07/02/2012  832            PD  39.27022   -76.63926
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr` by capturing as two groups with only the numeric elements with dots and discard the rest in 'Location.1'

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  extract(Location.1, into = c('alt', 'lng'), "\\(([0-9.]+),\\s+(-*[0-9.]+).")
# CC.Number       Date Time Accident.Type       alt        lng
#1 12T008826 07/01/2012 1630            PD  39.26699 -76.560642
#2 12L005385 07/02/2012 1229            PD 39.000549 -76.399312
#3 12L005388 07/02/2012 1229            PD  39.00058 -76.399267
#4 12T008851 07/02/2012  445            PI  39.26367  -76.56648
#5 12T008858 07/02/2012  802            PD 39.240862 -76.599017
#6 12T008860 07/02/2012  832            PD  39.27022  -76.63926
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this also, assuming `dat1` is your original dataset name, we can use strsplit and gsub. First we replace commas and parenthesis with nothing using gsub and then using strsplit to split the values by spaces:

```
df1 <- setNames(data.frame(do.call("rbind",strsplit(gsub("\\(|\\)|,","",dat1$Location.1),split=" "))),c("Lat","Long"))
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(dat1[,1:(length(dat1)-1)],df1))

# CC.Number     Date Time Accident.Type       Lat       Long
# 1 12T008826 07/01/12 1630            PD  39.26699 -76.560642
# 2 12L005385 07/02/12 1229            PD 39.000549 -76.399312
# 3 12L005388 07/02/12 1229            PD  39.00058 -76.399267
# 4 12T008851 07/02/12  445            PI  39.26367  -76.56648
# 5 12T008858 07/02/12  802            PD 39.240862 -76.599017
# 6 12T008860 07/02/12  832            PD  39.27022  -76.63926
```

Answer (score 1):

In *base* you can use `trimws` to remove `()` and `read.table` to split at `,`.

```
cbind(md[1:4], read.table(sep=",", text=trimws(md$Location.1, whitespace = "[ ()]"),
 col.names=c("alt", "lng")))
#  CC.Number        Date Time  Accident.Type      alt       lng
#1 12T008826  07/01/2012 1630             PD 39.26699 -76.56064
#2 12L005385  07/02/2012 1229             PD 39.00055 -76.39931
#3 12L005388  07/02/2012 1229             PD 39.00058 -76.39927
#4 12T008851  07/02/2012  445             PI 39.26367 -76.56648
#5 12T008858  07/02/2012  802             PD 39.24086 -76.59902
#6 12T008860  07/02/2012  832             PD 39.27022 -76.63926
```

Data:

```
md <- structure(list(CC.Number = c("12T008826", "12L005385", "12L005388", 
"12T008851", "12T008858", "12T008860"), Date = c(" 07/01/2012", 
" 07/02/2012", " 07/02/2012", " 07/02/2012", " 07/02/2012", " 07/02/2012"
), Time = c(1630L, 1229L, 1229L, 445L, 802L, 832L), Accident.Type = c("            PD", 
"            PD", "            PD", "            PI", "            PD", 
"            PD"), Location.1 = c("  (39.26699, -76.560642)", 
" (39.000549, -76.399312)", "  (39.00058, -76.399267)", "   (39.26367, -76.56648)", 
" (39.240862, -76.599017)", "   (39.27022, -76.63926)")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```