# Separate string with keeping separator

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a datafarme:

```
ID    Value
1    message "some text"
2    more messages "some more text"
```

I separate a column in my dataframe in this way:

```
df <- df  %>%
  separate(Value, c("message", "text"), ' "', remove = TRUE)
```

But i get this:

```
ID    message             text
1    message          some text"
2    more messages    some more text"
```

Instead of this:

```
ID    message             text
1    message          "some text"
2    more messages    "some more text"
```

How could i keep that separator? I also tried this, but makes the same mistake:

```
df %>% 
  tidyr::extract(col = "Value",
                 into = c("message", "text"),
                 regex = '^(.*?) "(.*?)$', remove = FALSE)
```

Comment: Try `'\\s+(?=")'` with `separate` or `'^([^"]*)\\s(".*)'` with `extract`

Comment: Reopened since [Split a column into 2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898329) is not dealing with the current problem, it just helps with the code that OP already uses.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
separate(Value, c("message", "text"), '\\s+(?=")', remove = TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WTyLEJ/2/).

The `\s+(?=")` pattern matches 1 or more whitespaces that are immediately followed with a `"` char.

Alternatively, with `extract`, you may use

```
tidyr::extract(col = "Value",
                 into = c("message", "text"),
                 regex = '^([^"]*)\\s(".*)', remove = FALSE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WTyLEJ/1). The regex means:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1 (*`message`*): any zero or more chars other than `"`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(".*)` - Group 2 (*`text`*): `"` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible